# Put hyphen on the margin, not in the text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, hyphenation

Normally Latex puts hyphens inside the text:

```
------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor  sit amet, consec-
tetuer adipiscing elit.  Aenean com-
modo ligula eget dolor.  Aenean mas-
sa. Cum sociis natoque  penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nasce-
tur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pre-
tium quis, sem. Nulla consequat mas-
sa  quis  enim.  Donec  pede  justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputa-
te eget, arcu.
------------------------------------
```

But I want to put it beside the text, because it is easier on the eyes and better for the reading flow:

```
------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte-
tuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus  et  magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridi-
culus mus. Donec quam felis, ultrici-
es  nec,  pellentesque  eu,  pretium
quis,  sem.  Nulla  consequat  massa
quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringil-
la vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
arcu.
------------------------------------
```

I know that it is possible because I have seen it in some PDFs which were most likely created using Latex, but I did not find out how it is done.

Comment: +1 for the challenge, but not for the visual effect.

Comment: @Kay - The easiest way is to `\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}`.  Check its excellent documentation for all the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dislike the idea of having the dashes in the margin, but you could do so by increasing the protrusion factor of `microtype`.

This will also push other stuff like periods and the little hook of the "t" into the margin, but this would just be consistent. Have a look, if this is what you want:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[factor=2100]{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6cm}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much  Arash Esbat and LaRiFaRi! `microtype` was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In ConTeXt it's relatively easy with `protrusion=pure`:

```
\definefontfeature[default][default][protrusion=pure]

\setupalign[hanging]

\starttext
\input tufte
\stoptext
```

[image]